Add thousands separator ipython output
As the heading says, is it possible to add the same thousands separator that we use on the input to the output of ipython?
I.e. from:
In [1]: 20_000_000/2
Out[1]: 10000000

to
In [1]: 20_000_000/2
Out[1]: 10_000_000

